# Compiling Jade into HTML using gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, gulp

I want to compile jade in html using gulp-jade. But after the task in the "build" folder does not have html files.

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/assets/template/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'jade'}));
});
```

Command-line:

```
PS E:\WORKS\fitover> gulp jade
[21:09:36] Using gulpfile E:\WORKS\fitover\gulpfile.js
[21:09:36] Starting 'jade'...
[21:09:36] 'jade' all files 0 B
[21:09:36] Finished 'jade' after 372 ms
```

Comment: search npm for grunt jade, there are a couple preconfigured task runners

Comment: @Plato, op asked for Gulp though.  @EduardGorte Make sure you're using the [gulp-jade plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade) if using gulp.  Take a look at their example docs and let us know if you still have questions.  The only thing that sticks out from your question, what does this statement do?  `$.size({title: 'jade'})`    I would think you're very last bit of logic should be the pipe to the destination

Comment: @JustinMaat I am sure that the use gulp-jade.
This statement calculates the size of the files certan job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on Ubuntu - the same result.
The solution is found. Not sure that this is the right decision, but it works. After commenting @Plato, I read the [guide](https://mijingo.com/blog/grunt-gulp-together-at-last), and use the grunt-contrib-jade combined with a [gulp-grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-grunt).

Comment: Please post some actual code with your answer to show the config you ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`.pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))`

Or make sure the relative path to your build file is correct from your gulp task.